# How to Fill Multiple File Names in ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

Hello Advanced people :)

I have a listbox with the file names on my app. I want to fill a combobox with the same names.
Looking for a more focused example of my case?

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frm_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Meteo";

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(path));
            }

        }

        else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Директорията Meteo не е октирта в системен диск 'C:\'");
            Application.ExitThread();
        }      
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with - you've got adding the files, and adding the paths in - what specifically is not working

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Want to fill comboBox2 with Names on all files.

Comment: I think this code should work.  You can further improve it by setting data Source instead of populating each item using foreach.  Also, you should not do such activity on UI thread as it may cause lag while loading your screen.

Comment: @BenJohnson if you want the name of your files in combo2, then do the same adding them to combo2.. Your problem is unclear

Comment: Add `comboBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));` in 1st `foreach` loop.